# How can I get subwindowtitle to variable?

Tags: powershell

The application using window title for print thread status,
So I found the powershell script like below.

```
Get-Process |where {$_.mainWindowTitle} |format-table mainwindowtitle
```

This is perfect script but The application has 2 windows, and MainWindowTitle is just dialog, But needed information is not that.

How Can I get another windowtitle from powershell, when the process has 2 windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following to get the child window:

```
Get-Process | where {$_.mainWindowTitle} | Get-ChildWindow
```

Comment: Get-ChildWindow is not recognized command. Get-ChildItem seem not same.